# How to clone value of particular key of JavaScript object to a new variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object in javascript.

```
info = { bio: {Age:21,Name:"John",Gender:"Male"}, qualification:{matricscore: 92, highschool: 80} }
```

I want to create a new object **profile** in which I want the value of the key **bio**. It will look somewhat like this.

```
profile = { Age:21,Name:"John",Gender:"Male" }
```

What should I do?

Comment: `Object.assign(profile, info.bio)` will copy the inner object so that changes to info.bio won't be reflected in profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
info = { bio: {Age:21,Name:"John",Gender:"Male"}, qualification:{matricscore: 92, highschool: 80} }


const profile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(info['bio']));
console.log(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
const profile = info.bio;
```

Comment: This works but the problem is it puts values in the profile using pass by reference method, so when I tried to change the profile, the changes got reflected in info.profile also.

Comment: That is expected behavior. JavaScript is a pass-by-value language. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are also missing quotes,
It will look something like:

```
var profile = info.bio;
```

Also, change your dictionary to:

```
{"bio":{"Age":21,"Name":"John","Gender":"Male"},"qualification":{"matricscore":92,"highschool":80}}
```

Comment: This works but the problem is it puts values in the profile using pass by reference method, so when I tried to change the profile, the changes got reflected in info.profile also.

Answer (score 0):

var profile  = info.bio;

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  info = { bio: {Age:21,Name:"John",Gender:"Male"}, qualification:{matricscore: 92, highschool: 80} };
 console.log( info.bio ); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Click to </h1>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click and see console</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Simple way to get bio from info.